# Minimum order subtotal for customer group

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, customer-group

Whats the best way to set a minimum subtotal for customer group? Is this even possible in native Magento?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible but you need some customization.

Magento check the `min Order amount` from `validateMinimumAmount` function of checkout address object means Sales quote addess object (class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`). You can rewrite the class and override the method

You need fetch quote Customer group and put minimum amount according to customer group.

and logic should be like that

```
class Your_Module_Model_Quote_Address extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
{

 public function validateMinimumAmount()
 {
     $result = parent::validateMinimumAmount();
     if (!$result) {
         return false;
     }

    $customergroupId=$this->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId();


    $CustomGroupMinprice=array(1=>100,2=>500,3=>200);

    if(!is_null($customergroupId) && array_key_exists($customergroupId,$CustomGroupMinprice)){
        foreach($CustomGroupMinprice as $key=>$value):
        if($customergroupId==$key && $this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() < $value):
        return false;
        break;
        endif;
        endforeach;


    }elseif($this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() < $amount) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

in `$CustomGroupMinprice=array(1=>100,2=>500,3=>200)`, `1,2,3` mean `customer group id` and `100,300,200 its respective minimum amount`

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion, using an extension is the simplest way to set up minimum order subtotal for customer group.

Magento default only supports setting minimum order amount, bu not for specific customer group.

You can read about this extension to limit order amount that each customer group has to meet

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/minimum-order-amount-for-customer-group-extension.html